# WPF: Styles not applied

Tags: wpf, ribbon

i have a setup like

```
<ribbon:RibbonGallery>
    <ribbon:RibbonGallery.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ribbon:RibbonGalleryItem">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
        </Style>
    </ribbon:RibbonGallery.Resources>

    </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
    <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory x:Name="themeColors" Header="Theme Colors" MinColumnCount="10" MaxColumnCount="10">
        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
    </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
</ribbon:RibbonGallery>
```

my width and height are not applied to the rectangles. i wondering whats wrong

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your style a `Key` and then reference that key in your code:

```
    <Style x:Key="RectStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
    </Style>
```

Then:

```
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource RectStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
```

To get the style to apply to **all** elements of a type you need to define it like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
```

Use the former if you want to have several styles for an element and choose which one you want to apply.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx)

Comment: ooo, but why does the 1st style work? `<Style TargetType="ribbon:RibbonGalleryItem">`. and i just tried, `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">` doesnt work too ...